# Int in raw_input does not work

Tags: python

```
while True:
    a = raw_input("Your number: ")
    if a == int: # letters:
        if a > 0 and a % 3 == 0:
            print 'fizz'
        if a > 0 and a % 5 == 0:
            print 'buzz'
        if a > 0 and a % 3 != 0 and a % 5 != 0:
            print a
        if a <= 0:
            print 'bad value'
    else:
        print "Not integer, try again"`
```

How do I make this `raw_input` work? I want this to run the game when the user input is an integer and "try again" when it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input` is a string.  You can convert it to an int using `int`.  If it's not convertible, this returns an error.  So use try... except to handle the error.  It's a good idea to put as little as possible into the try... part because otherwise some other error might be accidentally caught.  Then put in a `continue` into the `except` part to skip back to the start.

```
while True:
    try:
        a= int(raw_input("Your number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "not integer, try again"
        continue
    if a > 0:
        if a % 3 == 0:
            print 'fizz'
        if a % 5 == 0:
            print 'buzz'
        if a % 3 != 0 and a % 5 != 0:
            print a
    else:  #a<=0
            print 'bad value'
```

Answer (score 5):

`raw_input()` always returns a string. If you want to make it an int, call the `int()` builtin function. If the contents of the string cannot be converted, a `ValueError` will be raised. You can build the logic of your program around that, if you wish.